# how to use imageJ to merge different channels and do a z stack average

Tags: imagej, imagej-hyperstack

I have ten tiff files and each of them contains two channels imaging data, I want to labeling different colors for the two channels and after that do a z projection, anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make yourself familiar with ImageJ's concepts of displaying [pseudocolor and composite images](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-9.html#sub:Pseudocolor-Images).

Use [*File > Import > Image Sequence...*](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-26.html#sub:Image-Sequence...) to open your tiff files as a stack. 
You might need to use [*Image > Hyperstacks > Stack to Hyperstack...*](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-28.html#sub:Stack-to-Hyperstack...) to convert your stack into a 2-channel, 10-slice hyperstack.
Then use [*Image > Stacks > Z Project...*](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-28.html#sub:Z-Project...) to create the z projection.

Using the [macro recorder](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-31.html#sub:Record...) while performing these commands will give you the code (needed to [automate](http://fiji.sc/Introduction_into_Macro_Programming) the task):

```bs
run("Image Sequence...", "open=/path/to/your/files file=tiff sort");
run("Stack to Hyperstack...", "order=xyczt(default) channels=2 slices=10 frames=1 display=Color");
run("Z Project...", "projection=[Average Intensity]");
```